# Button click doen't start activity in Gridview android

Tags: android, android-activity, gridview, android-imagebutton

I have a gridview inside a recyclerview in which i have put ImageButtons.
**Problem**:when i click on any of these buttons the resulting activity doesn't open up in fact nothing happens.I tried to see if the call statement is reached by putting a log statement but that also not showing up.As you can see currently i have assigned activities to first four buttons and i'm talking about those 4 buttons.
My files are:

1.MainActivity.xml

```
package com.defcomdevs.invento16;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,MyAdapter.clickListener {
private CollapsingToolbarLayout mcollapsingToolbar;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
int backButtonCount = 0;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private NestedScrollView mnestedScrollView;
private Button button;
//    GridView mygrid;
private ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    adapter=new MyAdapter(this,getdata());
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setClicklistener(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
    //button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
    mcollapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    mcollapsingToolbar.setTitle("INVENTO '16");
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            callRegister();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void callRegister() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (backButtonCount >= 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back button once again to close the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backButtonCount++;
    }

}
public List<ListItems> getdata(){
    List<ListItems> grid_data=new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icons={R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100};
    String[] texts=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Items);
    for (int i=0;i<icons.length&&i<texts.length;i++){
        ListItems current=new ListItems();
        current.iconId=icons[i];
        current.IconName=texts[i];
        grid_data.add(current);
    }
    return grid_data;
}
  /* public void setalarm(View view){
    if(view.getId()==R.id.setalarm){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.about_college) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.cse) {

    } else if (id == R.id.it) {

    } else if (id == R.id.ece) {

    } else if (id == R.id.mech) {

    } else if (id == R.id.techquiz) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Techquiz.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.BackTrack) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Backtrack.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.LanGaming) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,LanGaming.class));

    }else if (id == R.id.DeadLock) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Deadlock.class));

    }
    else if (id == R.id.printing) {

    } else if (id == R.id.Big) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nand) {

    } else if (id == R.id.cryo) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void ItemClick(View view, int position) {
    if (position==0){
        Log.d("Item click","Reached here");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Backtrack.class));
    }
    if (position==1){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Deadlock.class));
    }
    if (position==2){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Techquiz.class));
    }
    if (position==3){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,LanGaming.class));
    }
    if (position==4){

    }
    if (position==5){

    }
    if (position==6){

    }
    if (position==7){

    }
}
}
```

2.Adapter file:

```
package com.defcomdevs.invento16;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

  public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>    {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_LIST = 1;
private clickListener click;
List<ListItems> dataList = Collections.emptyList();

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ListItems> data) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.dataList = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleitem, parent, false);
        ItemHolder holder = new ItemHolder(view);
        return holder;

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ItemHolder itemHolder=(ItemHolder) holder;
        ListItems current = dataList.get(position);
        itemHolder.iconTxt.setText(current.IconName);
        itemHolder.icon_id.setImageResource(current.iconId);
        itemHolder.icon_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
        itemHolder.icon_id.setAlpha(180);
}

public  void setClicklistener(clickListener click){
    this.click=click;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {

    ImageButton icon_id;
    TextView iconTxt;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        icon_id = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        iconTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(click!=null){
            click.ItemClick(v,getPosition());
        }
    }

}
public interface clickListener{
    void ItemClick(View view,int position);
}
}
```

please help.Thanks

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.defcomdevs.invento16.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/picture"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="90dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Comment: Maybe you need to post also your `activity_main.xml` file to see how your buttons are defined in there.

Comment: i have defined a common layout for all buttons and the images are set programmatically.

Comment: So you are sure the id's are correct?

Comment: i have put up my xml file.And sir, i 'am checking on the position of the button.that is if position==1 then open this activity.

Comment: Are all the activities declared in the manifest?

Comment: yes.All activities are declared in manifest.

Comment: @Alex found the solution instead of `onClickListener` i used `onItemTouchListener`.This solved the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.The problem was that the recycler view was taking my tap gesture and was interpreting as a scroll gesture so the click was not at all performed.I replaced `onClickListener` with `onItemTouchListener` and override the method `SimpleOnGestureListener`.I have uploaded the changes here in this code fragment.

```
 class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {   //to intercept touch before RecyclerView picks up ACTION_UP or ACTION_DOWN

    public ClickListener clickListener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener=clickListener;
        gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child=recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                if(child!=null&&clickListener!=null){
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child,recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
        if (child!=null&&clickListener!=null&&gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            clickListener.onClick(child,rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}

public static interface ClickListener {  //Interface to detect touch
    public void onClick(View v, int position);

    public void onLongClick(View v, int position);
}
```

}